# Granting full permissions to everyone on newly created folder from within c#

Tags: c#, folder-permissions

Im saving images from a URL list but trying to duplicate the folder structure locally.

I parse the URL to give me the folder structure I want :

Example:

```
URL =  www.site.com/images/folder1/folder2/image
```

My local base folder is `mydocs/site/images` 
I split the url string up and am able to recursively create the proper folder structure using:

```
 if (!Directory.Exists(finalLocalFolder))
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(finalLocalFolder);
    }
```

Everything works great UNTIL I try and save the image to the folder using :

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile(remoteUrl, finalLocalFolder);
```

In which case, I am told that access to that folder is denied.

> "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'mydocs\images\test\test1\test\2\3m' is denied."

So I am guessing that I need to create a step in the CREATEDIRECTORY area where I immediately grant access to that folder.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: That's odd. Folders generally inherit the permissions of their parent which also usually includes the Creator/Owner having full permission. Are you trying to save to "Program Files" or something?

Comment: I don't mean the type of file you are trying to save, I mean the `%ProgramFiles%` folder

Comment: `'mydocs\images\test\test1\test\2\3m'` doesn't look like a complete path to me. Seems something like `C:\` is missing at the beginning?

Comment: NO! BUT!!! you got me looking and thinking.  This is my bad...so sorry.  Ill delete this -- I forgot to give the final path an actual FILE name (DOH!)

Comment: @UweKeim -- that was just for an example Uwe.

Answer (score 1):

I can close this if you would like - but just to put up what my problem was... here it is:

In here:  webClient.DownloadFile(remoteUrl, finalLocalFolder);

finalLocalFolder was ending up something like:  "C:\mydocs\images\test\test2"  when IT SHOULD HAVE BEEN  "C:\mydocs\images\test\test2\theimagefilename.jpg"

Stupid moment.  Sorry.